# wp7 TemplateBinding Content not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, templatebinding

I am new in working with wpf and currently I am trying to do the following: I have created a simple ContenctControl (CtrpushPinContent) that contains a TextBlock:

```
<ContentControl x:Class="CtrpushPinContent" ...
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{x:Null}">
<Border BorderThickness="3" Name="border1" CornerRadius="15" BorderBrush="#FF070707" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3" Name="border2" CornerRadius="15" Background="#FF413E3E">
                    <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4" Foreground="White" />
                </Border>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
</ContentControl>
```

The cs file looks like this:

```
 public partial class CtrpushPinContent : ContentControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("Text",
                                        typeof(string),
                                        typeof(CtrpushPinContent),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

        public string Text
        {
            get { return textBlock1.Text; }
            set { textBlock1.Text = value; }
        }
        public CtrpushPinContent()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

On the main PhoneApplicationPage  I try to do the following:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
<Style TargetType="my:Pushpin" x:Key="PushpinStyle">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="my:Pushpin">
                        <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Grid Background="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MinHeight="31" MinWidth="29">
                                    <LJTileSources:CtrpushPinContent HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="4" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
                                </Grid>
                                <Image Source="/WifiHotSpot;component/Images/blackPinNoShadow.png"  Width="54" Height="54" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<Grid>
      <my:Map Margin="0,1,0,0" Name="map1" LogoVisibility="Collapsed" Height="576"  CredentialsProvider="key" ZoomLevel="2">
      <my:Pushpin Style="{StaticResource PushpinStyle}" Content="Test" Location="50.0863762,14.42814" PositionOrigin="BottomLeft"></my:Pushpin>
                    </my:Map>
</Grid>
```

However my solution is not working. I cannot see any effect of the

```
<my:Pushpin Style="{StaticResource PushpinStyle}" Content="Test" .../>
```

I believe the problem is somewhere in the style declaration:

```
 <LJTileSources:CtrpushPinContent HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="4" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
```

because when I change it to

```
<LJTileSources:CtrpushPinContent HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Text="TestText" Margin="4" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
```

it displays the "TestText" as required.

Answer (score 0):

In your case for solve this problem quickly you need to implement this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty =          
     DependencyProperty.Register("Text",
                                        typeof(string),
                                        typeof(CtrpushPinContent),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnTextChanged));

        public string Text
        {
            get { return textBlock1.Text; }
            set { textBlock1.Text = value; }
        }

        private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((CtrpushPinContent)sender).textBlock1.Text = (string)e.NewValue;
        }

        public CtrpushPinContent()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

When you set text in Pushpin template:

```
<LJTileSources:CtrpushPinContent HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                                                     Margin="4" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
```

you don't set Text property in your control, you set value of dependency property CaptionProperty, because you registered it with name "Text". So when you set Text from xaml, you set exactly Caption property, not Text property of your control. So you need to create event of changing this dependency property for updating text in textBox1.